# Meta SE header banner contains the old Stack Overflow logo icon

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, design, logo

This is the MSE banner background:

[image]

Note the Stack Overflow logo contains **6** overflowing bars.

Here's the *current* Stack Overflow icon:

[image: SO]

*DISCREPANCY ALERT!*

---

All out-of-date icons:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) - [Report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267841/202832)
- [Electrical Engineering SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) - [Report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267841/meta-se-header-banner-contains-the-old-stack-overflow-logo-icon?noredirect=1#comment868549_267841)

Comment: Missing FHRC!1! Fixed. :D

Comment: While you're at it, the Electrical Enginering.SE logo is out of date (due to site design update). Are there any other sites which have had their icons changed?

Comment: @angussidney Added bullet list to post -- I suppose only comments will tell but I didn't recognize any changes.

Comment: @kos [status-fixed]

Comment: [Partially fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270730/mse-still-uses-the-old-so-logo)